# How to maintain the same row height for 16:9 aspect ratio mat-grid-tile if it's come multiple columns and rows in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="columnCount" [rowHeight]="aspectRatio" [gutterSize]="gutterSize">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let matrix of selectedLayout;let i = index" [colspan]="matrix.cols [rowspan]="matrix.rows">
  <img [src]="imageListData[i].path" [alt]="imageListData[i].altTag"/>
  </span>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX4T2.png)

Comment: Here i'm using mat-grid layout for image gallery to show multiple images. so i'm using 16:9 aspect ratio. When it comes to multiple dynamic images into the mat-grid, the height will be dynamically changing. how to keep the same height?

Comment: would be better if you include a snippet of the rendered HTML, not the angular code